# Bypass cache from single IP with NGINX

Tags: nginx

I want to setup NGINX to serve content from the cache to everybody but one IP address.

The 2 goals I want to achieve are:

1. make sure that from the specified IP I never hit the cache but will be served the actual file on disk (so if I remove the file it should immediately give a 404)
2. for all the other IPs: if content is requested that is not yet in the cache immediately load it from file and store it in the cache (so if I remove the file it should served for the duration of the cache)

This is my configuration so far:

```
server {
    listen                      80;
    listen                      127.0.0.1:9999 default;
    server_name                 storage.example.com;
    charset                     utf-8;
    autoindex                   off;

    access_log                  "/var/log/nginx/storage.access.log";
    udplog_tag                  "www.example.com/storage";

    set_real_ip_from            127.0.0.0/8;
    set_real_ip_from            unix:;
    real_ip_header              X-Real-IP;

    server_name_in_redirect     off;
    port_in_redirect            off;

    location /a/ {
        alias           "/storage/public/a/";
    }

    location /b/ {
        alias           "/storage/public/b/";
    }
}

server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     static.example.com;
    charset         utf-8;
    autoindex       off;

    access_log      "/var/log/nginx/static.access.log";
    udplog_tag      "www.example.com/static";

    location / {
        proxy_set_header      Host "$host";
        proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:9999/;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 15;
        proxy_send_timeout    60;
        proxy_read_timeout    60;
        include               proxy_cache;
        proxy_redirect        default;
    }
}
```

This is the content of the included file proxy_cache:

```
proxy_cache             cache;
proxy_cache_key         "$scheme://$host$uri";
proxy_cache_use_stale   error;
proxy_next_upstream     off;
proxy_cache_min_uses    1;
proxy_cache_valid       200 302 1h;
proxy_cache_valid       301 1d;
proxy_cache_valid       any 30m;
proxy_buffers           128 4k;
```

What I would like to do is something similar:

```
if ( $remote_addr != "ip to exclude" ) 
 { include proxy_cache; }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bypassing the cache is done with [`proxy_cache_bypass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_bypass). It will cause the cache to be bypassed if any value you pass to it is nonzero.

But before you can do that, you need a variable to pass to it. In your case this can be done with a [`geo`](http://nginx.org/r/geo) directive to examine the remote IP address. (It could also be done with a `map`, which is a more general directive along the same lines.)

So, first place within your `http` block:

```
geo $ip_cache_bypass {
    default         0;
    192.0.2.81      1;
}
```

Then in your proxy configuration directives:

```
proxy_cache_bypass $ip_cache_bypass;
```

The cache will then be bypassed for the IP address 192.0.2.81. You can add as many IP addresses or CIDR ranges as you wish in the `geo` block.